# Cant boot after cancelling MiniTool Partition Wizard

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted, bootloader

I wanted to resize the windows partition using gparted but it wont work, so i used Mini Tool Partition wizard. After first step was made it started to wipe an unallocated space (my wrong) so i canceled it rebooting the computer. Now , when I try to boot, it says something like:

Error:Unknown FileSystem

Grub rescue>

I'm running a bootable live usb with fedora, and it says that there is no data on the hard drive.

I have important data both on ubuntu and windows and need to save it.

I think that some of the linux partitions are unmounted or replaced by the live session.

Note: The resize was completely done and I didn't touched any ubuntu partitions.

EDIT: Using the Fedora Disk application I found all partitions but still cant boot.

I discovered this:
Disk is OK, **8 bad sectors** (38° C / 100° F)
I think that some of partitions have an invalid file format or are replaced bz the live session partitons.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn1i1.png

Answer (score 0):

> "Fedora Disk application"?

Are you sure you're using Ubuntu after all?

From what you describe, the data on your drive has become inaccessible, possibly due to corruption of the on-disc structures (partition table).

- If you have a full system backup, use it now.
- If you don't and the drive had important data, turn off the computer **immediately** and take the disk to data recovery specialist.
- If you don't but the data wasn't so important, re-install.

Comment: Yes, im using Ubuntu but i cant acces it and the only way to boot the computer is using an live usb.